# Can I use container tag inside a container-fluid tag?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am currently designing a website and need to know if I can use container tag inside a container-fluid tag? Is it a good design approach to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* do this if you want, though it is generally not necessary, as their primary purpose is to be an external wrapper. The main thing to be aware of is the `15px` padding on either side of a Bootstrap container, as well as their varying `max-width` media queries.

When nested, a child .container will not fill the width of the screen at any point.

[Bootstrap Containers](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#containers) overview.

[Bootstrap.css Source Code](https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css). Open this, `ctrl + f` and search **.container**, **.container-fluid**, and the **sm**, **md**, **lg**, and **xl** container sizes to see how they are styled.

Open the following code snippet example in **Full Page** mode and re-size to see their effects within .container-fluid, without .container-fluid, and with several .container divs nested within eachother.

```css
.container-fluid {
  background:pink
}
.container, .container-sm, .container-md, .container-lg, .container-xl {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: lightblue;
}
.not-a-bootstrap-container {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h2>
  Within container-fluid
  </h2>
  <div class="container">
    .container
  </div>
  <div class="container-sm">
    .container-sm
  </div>
  <div class="container-md">
    .container-md
  </div>
  <div class="container-lg">
    .container-lg
  </div>
  <div class="container-xl">
    .container-xl
  </div>
</div>
<div class="not-a-bootstrap-container">
  <h2>
    Without container-fluid
  </h2>
  <div class="container">
    .container
  </div>
  <div class="container-sm">
    .container-sm
  </div>
  <div class="container-md">
    .container-md
  </div>
  <div class="container-lg">
    .container-lg
  </div>
  <div class="container-xl">
    .container-xl
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h2>
    Multiple nested containers (within Container-Fluid)
  </h2>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="container">
        Three .container divs nested within eachother in a .container-fluid
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the `container` tag inside of a `container-fluid` tag. It all depends on the needs. Let say you have a scenario where you want to make the `navbar` of full screen width and page content to be in a single centered container.

There is nothing like bad approach in this.